# Ez Publish - Ez Flow - Editinlocks errors

Tags: ezpublish

I have to upgrade an old website in ez publish 4.2. There is a class which use a layout attribut (ez flow layout and manual blocks). In front office, the result is perfect, but in backend, i can't change the content.

In bakcend, it's possible to choose differents layout but there is nothing to change blocks content. 
When i look for on google, on official documentation, i see how to change the content, but in my case, the display is different, there is nothing...

Someone can help me ? I think it's config file problem but i don't find it.

Thks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having problem with Override.ini (or block.ini in case of ezflow).

in eZPublish every view should first be enabled and entered in Override.ini so that ezpublish knows that this is going to override which template.